# Return result only if 1 row exits | mySQL

Tags: mysql

Essentially, I need to return a result if row count of result is 1. Meaning if there is more than 1 result for the Select statement it must return nothing.

For example if: `SELECT Person WHERE Job = "Construction" OR "Officer"`

return no results

but if: `SELECT Person WHERE Job = "Clerk"` return the 1 row

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: `WHERE Job = "Construction" OR "Officer"` is not a valid constraint. What do you really want to achieve? Why shouldn't rows 2, 4, or 5 be returned? Why should the condition `Job = "Clerk"` return the first row, where the `Job` value does not equal `Clerk`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Job` column can never be `NULL`, aggregation might be the simplest option here:

```sql
SELECT Person
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Person
HAVING MIN(Job) = MAX(Job);
```

If you really need the entire rows, then use:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Person
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Person
    HAVING MIN(Job) = MAX(Job)
) t2
    ON t2.Person = t1.Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE {conditions}
  AND 1 = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM table
            WHERE {the same conditions} )
```